# Calling the google client two times giving fatal error

Tags: php, google-signin

I have a made a simple script that is trying to login and register with google but for that i need to have two different urls. One that should be redirected to `login.php` and one to be `register.php`. I was not getting way how to do that so i just copied the google client folder where all the config files are kept and i renamed it and changed the redirect url to `register.php` and one to `login.php`. I thought calling the files two times will work fine for me but no it is giving an fatal error. The error is

```
<b>Fatal error</b> :  Cannot redeclare class Google_Exception in E:\wordpress\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\shoprang\name2\Google_Client.php on line 407
```

Here is my php

```
<?php
require_once 'name1/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'name1/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google UserInfo PHP Starter Application");
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
echo $authUrl."<br>";
require_once 'name2/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'name2/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
$cliente = new Google_Client();
$cliente->setApplicationName("Google UserInfo PHP Starter Application");
$oauth2e = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
$authUrle = $client->createAuthUrle();
echo $authUrle;
?>
```

Please help me as i am beginner to login api with google. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so so simple, you are including the files 2 times. Even though you think you have `require_once` but the locations are different so they get included again

Remove these

```
require_once 'name2/Google_Client.php';                     //remove this
require_once 'name2/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';      // and this
```

Because both these files have already been included above

```
require_once 'name1/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'name1/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
```

When the Google Client library file is included for the second time, it tries to re-declare the class and hence you get that error.

Comment: The above file contains different credentials.

Comment: Libraries shouldnt really have credentials. There must be something you are doing wrong. Define credentials separately but use 1 base class for Google Client library.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is saying you are declaring the google class once again. Just remove two of those require once.

```
  require_once 'name2/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'name2/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: What is different in this answer from the existing answer?